# How to validate a promotional input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been so far able to achieve how a normal promo box should look like. So when you click on the text the onclick function will trigger and open the input field and "apply" button, and everything is working order.

What I want to achieve is a validation on the input field that if the field is empty and someone is trying to click on "Apply" button. It should give an error message saying "You must enter discount code"

Can someone help me?

```js
$("#promo-code").on("click", function() {
  $("#promo-code").hide();
  $("#promo-box").show();
  $("#codediv").show();
  $('.trash-checkout').hide();
});

$('#applybtn').click(function() {
  $("#promo-box").hide();
  $("#codediv").html("Promo code:<span><a href='javascript:void(1);' id='edit-promo-code'>" + $(".checkout-promo-code-input").val() + "</a></span>").show();
  $('.trash-checkout').show();
});

$('#removecode').click(function() {
  $(".checkout-promo-code-input").val('');
  $("#codediv").html("").hide();
  $('.trash-checkout').hide();
  $("#promo-code").show();
});

$('#promo-code-outer').on("click", '#edit-promo-code', function() {
  $("#codediv").hide();
  $('.trash-checkout').hide();
  $("#promo-box").show();
});
```

```css
.trash-checkout {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.trash-checkout:hover {
  color: #dc3545;
}

.promo-edit {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.promo-edit a {
  color: #000000;
}

#promo-code {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#promo-box,
#promo-box-mb {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="promo-code-outer">
  <div class="mt-3 text-center"><a href="javascript:void(1);" id="promo-code">Apply a promo code</a></div>
  <div id="promo-box">
    <span class="col-9 float-left pl-0 pr-0"><input type="text" class="checkout-promo-code-input" placeholder="Enter promo code"></span>
    <span class="col-3 float-left"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="applybtn">Apply</button></span>
  </div>
  <div class="float-left promo-edit display-none" id="codediv"></div>
  <div class="float-right" style="margin-left:50px;">
    <span class="trash-checkout" style="display: none;"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="removecode"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just check the value of the input.

```
$('#applybtn').click(function() {
    if ($("#promo-box input").val()){
      $("#promo-box").hide();
      $("#codediv").html("Promo code:<span><a href='javascript:void(1);' id='edit-promo-code'>" + $(".checkout-promo-code-input").val() + "</a></span>").show();
      $('.trash-checkout').show();
      }
      else{
      // do your error stuff
      }
    });
```

```js
$("#promo-code").on("click", function() {
  $("#promo-code").hide();
  $("#promo-box").show();
  $("#codediv").show();
  $('.trash-checkout').hide();
});

$('#applybtn').click(function() {
if ($("#promo-box input").val()){
  $("#promo-box").hide();
  $("#codediv").html("Promo code:<span><a href='javascript:void(1);' id='edit-promo-code'>" + $(".checkout-promo-code-input").val() + "</a></span>").show();
  $('.trash-checkout').show();
  }
  else{
    $("#promo-box input").css("border-color", "red");
    $( "#promo-box" ).append( "<p style='color: red;'>promo code is required</p>" );
  }
});

$('#removecode').click(function() {
  $(".checkout-promo-code-input").val('');
  $("#codediv").html("").hide();
  $('.trash-checkout').hide();
  $("#promo-code").show();
});

$('#promo-code-outer').on("click", '#edit-promo-code', function() {
  $("#codediv").hide();
  $('.trash-checkout').hide();
  $("#promo-box").show();
});
```

```css
.trash-checkout {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.trash-checkout:hover {
  color: #dc3545;
}

.promo-edit {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.promo-edit a {
  color: #000000;
}

#promo-code {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#promo-box,
#promo-box-mb {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="promo-code-outer">
  <div class="mt-3 text-center"><a href="javascript:void(1);" id="promo-code">Apply a promo code</a></div>
  <div id="promo-box">
    <span class="col-9 float-left pl-0 pr-0"><input type="text" class="checkout-promo-code-input" placeholder="Enter promo code"></span>
    <span class="col-3 float-left"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="applybtn">Apply</button></span>
  </div>
  <div class="float-left promo-edit display-none" id="codediv"></div>
  <div class="float-right" style="margin-left:50px;">
    <span class="trash-checkout" style="display: none;"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="removecode"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What this is doing is on every click its keep generating error message again and again: https://prnt.sc/pd1sen